# What would be the modern equivalent of " ... is around the corner yet"?

Tags: word-usage

Here's a neat article covering the differences between *yet* and *still*:

https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-still-and-yet.html

There is, in Mark Twain's *Connecticut Yankee*, a sentence that reads:

> I dropped a nickel out of the window and got my paper; the
> Adam-newsboy of the world went around the corner to get my change; is
> around the corner ***yet***.

The usage is not covered in the article. It is archaic. And *yet*, when you substitute "still," it does not sound as comical.

What would be the modern equivalent?

" ... has yet to come back from around the corner" is too long-winded to be funny, if you ask me.

Comment: Archaic? Sounds fine to me.

Comment: Seems slightly odd or old-fashioned to me. Lexico suggests [yet](https://www.lexico.com/definition/yet) meaning "Up until the present or a specified or implied time; by now or then" is used in a few contexts: most examples are with a negative ("I haven't told anyone else yet"), or with a superlative ("best yet"). Not sure if writing jokes is off-topic, but I think you'd have to reorder the sentence a bit, and don't know how you'd get a laugh.

Comment: You're almost certainly going to trade off comic effect for up-to-dateness. Many jokes are pretty strictly contextual.

Comment: Maybe "bounced away to get my change; has not bounced back (or rebounded) yet" !!

Comment: _Yet_ is not quite an NPI, but it appears most often in negative contexts, typically referring to something that has not happened but is expected to happen presently. The negative stretch of time has become associated with the use of _yet_ in contexts where _still_ is available, i.e, non-negative contexts referring to a length of time up to the present.

Answer (score 3):

The modern equivalent would be, "... and is around the corner still."

How do I know this?  Because when my mother told me her version of the Cinderella story when I was little, she would end with something like this:

> Cinderella and the prince lived happily ever after.  As for the stepmother and the ugly stepsisters, they didn't have Cinderella to boss around any more to do their housework.  And they're arguing about the housework still.

Comment: ...and _everyone_ knows that moms are always right, and they never lie! (possibly I am paraphrasing [_FireSign Theatre_)](https://everything2.com/title/Don%2527t+Crush+that+Dwarf%252C+Hand+Me+the+Pliers) https://everything2.com/title/Don%2527t+Crush+that+Dwarf%252C+Hand+Me+the+Pliers)